# Moq Verify or VerifyAll

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

We use Moq for our unit tests, I dont understand why we are doing the following with the VerifyAll call. Would there be a reason why this is done or can I just use the verify method?

```
createbleUtility.Verify(x => x.AuditCreatedItem(It.IsAny<TaskFinished>()), Times.Exactly(2));
createbleUtility.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: Ok so it makes sure you setup methods are called as well as as the verify that a method was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VerifyAll() is for verifying that all the expectations have been met.
It is not required if you only have one expectation and you use the verify 
as specified in your example